# Make AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate and AVContentKeySessionDelegate working together

Tags: ios, swift

I am using AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate to load subtitles and additional audio tracks (m2u8 playlist). I am using AVContentKeySession and AVContentKeySessionDelegate to decrypt content (DRM). Separately they both are working well: subtitles are loaded and displayed, AVPlayer ask for key and it is successfully served. However, when I use them together, AVPlayer never ask for its key through AVContentKeySessionDelegate.

I have tried to ask for key manually through processContentKeyRequest when I am inside resourceLoader. Even if I get content key, it looks like AVPlayer never received it.

I can't process key right inside AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate as I need tu solve dual expiry so I need to use AVContentKeySessionDelegate in order to receive didUpdatePersistableContentKey.

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource of AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate must return false in order key session loading is initiated.

Comment: Implemented the delegate methods of  AVContentKeySessionDelegate within my ViewController(so, the reference would be retained as long as my view controller is there).
 
My code snippet is:


     `let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoUrl)
     self.contentKeySession = AVContentKeySession(keySystem: .fairPlayStreaming)
     self.contentKeySession?.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
     self.contentKeySession?.addContentKeyRecipient(asset)`


But, its delegate methods are not being called.